# Deployed WAR with Web Console in JBOSS EAP

Tags: jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I tried to deploy my file.war with web console of JBOSS EAP (http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#standalone-deployments)
Deployement succedded but whent I tried access a WSservice of my WAR I got ´Error :  4040 Not Found ..´
So I look directory: 
**standalone/deployments** => No WAR file
**standalone/data/content/40/1ad4f7ab80a3921b9f550b6e7c55e36096021a** => No WAR file
**/standalone/tmp**/file.war => But into file.war it is empty I have not the file of my project..

Someone have an issue for resolve it ?

Comment: Does it show your deployment in the web console?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the archive with CLI or console it will not added to standalone/deployments!
It is stored in data/content but with a hash name. 
You can check the standalone.xml for the deployments element and see how it is deployed.
The recommended way is to use CLI/console to check the state of it.